# Calling Scala UDF in Pyspark JavaPackage is not callable error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to use a `scala` UDF in `pyspark`
My `scala` udf looks like the following.

```
package com.ParseGender
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._


object ParseGender{
      def testudffunction(s: String): String =  {
          if(List("cis female","f","female","woman","femake","female ",
                  "cis-female/femme","female (cis)","femail").contains(s.toLowerCase))
          "Female"
          else if(List("male","m","male-ish","maile","mal","male (cis)",
                         "make","male ","man","msle","mail","malr","cis man","cis male").contains(s.toLowerCase))
                "Male"
            else
                "Transgender"
        }
    def getFun(): UserDefinedFunction = udf(testudffunction _)
    }
```

I'm using `sbt package` to package it into `jars`. My `build.sbt` looks like the following

```
name := "ParseGender"
    version := "1.0"
    organization := "testcase"
    scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
    val sparkVersion = "2.3.0"

    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion)
```

And finally to test it I've a small pyspark program written up

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql.column import Column, _to_java_column, _to_seq

spark = SparkSession.builder \
     .master("local") \
     .appName("UDAF") \
     .getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

def test_udf(col):
  sc = spark.sparkContext
  _test_udf = sc._jvm.com.test.ParseGender.getFun()
  return Column(_test_udf.apply(_to_seq(sc, [col], _to_java_column)))

df = spark.createDataFrame(
  [("female",), ("male",), ("femail",)],
  ("text",)
)

df = df.withColumn('text2', test_udf(df['text']))
df.show(3)
```

I run it locally with `spark-submit` like so

```
spark-submit --jars /somepath/scala-2.11/parsegender_2.11-1.0.jar xyz.py
```

where `xyz.py` has the pyspark code above.

After issuing the submit I get the following error

```
    _test_udf = sc._jvm.com.test.ParseGender.getFun()
    TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

I suspect this has something to do with pyspark not able to read/detect the package, but I'm not sure. Could someone provide some pointers on how to fix this?

Comment: I think you should use this, to use the udf defined in package com.ParseGender _test_udf = sc._jvm.com.ParseGender.ParseGender.getFun()

Comment: @RangaVure That did the trick. thank you !

Comment: Pls upvote my comment :), thank you!